# How to fetch data from response._body in proper way?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

So starting first my nodejs server sends this as a response

> "["name1","name2","name3"]"

but my angular 2 code for service is

```
return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/folder').map((response:Response)=> {
       response.json();
     console.log(response); }
```

How do I fetch the array?

If I use response._body there will be an error in npm start stating "._body undefined", so I make it as a comment then after npm start I reverse back, I know it is not proper way. Here is the console.log of above service code

```
 Response
 headers: Headers
 ok:true
 status:200
 statusText:"OK"
 type:2
 url:"http://localhost:4000/folder"
 _body:"["name1","name2","name3"]"
 __proto__:Body
```

The main problem is to fetch in component in an array

Here, is the code I am trying

```
this.photoService.getAllfolder().subscribe(
data => {
  console.log(data);
},
error => {
      console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: okay thanks for the tips and thanks for down voting it and again thanks for not clearing my issue

Comment: There is no need for you to compound your first rudeness with a second one. If you remember that your questions here are not more important than other people's, you will do much better. Do please read the whole of the link I've supplied, it will help you avoid downvotes in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement in your mapping. Also if you then want to have the console log, you need to change the order. Your code should therefore look like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/folder')
   .map((response:Response)=> {
     console.log(response);
     return response.json(); // return
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am now getting error at                         `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Comment: Hmm... please compare your code to this plunker that all your code would be fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/eIQGIrvXqfTh012GGB6U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can get data in lot of ways easy way was response["_body"] or response.text()

```
return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/folder').map((response)=> {
       response["_body"];
     console.log(response); }
```

Comment: after doing so I get error cannot find name '_body'